# Parse flat JSON into nested object structure with Moshi

Tags: json, moshi

I'm working with an API that returns several JSON responses which have common data fields between them. I'm using Moshi to deserialize the responses into objects.

For example say a response from one API method call has this structure

```
class Book(
    val title: String,
    val genre: String,
    ...
    val authorName: String,
    val authorAge: Int,
    val authorCountry: String
}
```

And another one has this structure

```
class Article(
    val title: String,
    val subject: String,
    ...
    val authorName: String,
    val authorAge: Int,
    val authorCountry: String
}
```

I'm looking for a solution to be able to move the common fields (e.g., the author details) into a separate class and treat it as if it as if it came from a nested JSON structure, while the actual JSON received from the API is unchanged and still flat.

```
class Book(
    val title: String,
    val genre: String,
    ...
    val author: Author
}
```

I want to do this so I can:

1. Treat the author as a separate entity when needed without having to
   pass the `Book` or `Article` objects around
2. Avoid duplicating the `Author` fields

Current solutions I can think of are:

1. Use an intermediate class like the `EventJson` example in the Moshi docs.
   I want to avoid this because my data classes are quite large and I
   would have to duplicate all the fields in the intermediate class.
2. Make the `Book` and `Article` classes subclasses of `Author`. I
   don't like this because a Book is not an Author and because it doesn't let
   me treat the Author as a separate entity.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the EventJson approach is going to be easiest to maintain even if it requires a lot of code.